# Listeners showing nothing

Tags: jmeter, listeners

I've run a test in Jmeter with some listeners at the Thread Group node. While some of then show information others doesn't.
Does somebody know why the next listeners show no data, please?

- Generate summary results
- Simle data writer
- Response time graph
- Save response to a file (doesn't allow saving anything anywhere)

Comment: Have you installed TemproryrootCA certificate in browser which will be generated in Jmeter/bin ?

Comment: Yes, I installed it in my mobile device. I´m testing an android app.